# blank space in directory name causing error

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I have many directories which have blank space in their names.I have some scripts to be run on them.
Here is an example script

```
#!/bin/bash
docid='/home/deel/PDF/rant/spr 2008 Shree rose Visheshank'
p=1
while [ $p -lt 117 ]; do
cp $docid/$p.pdf ./
p=$p+1
done
```

Upon executing the above script I get following errors

```
cp: cannot stat `/home/deel/PDF/rant/spr': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `2008': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `Shree': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `rose': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `Visheshank/1.pdf': No such file or directory
./d2.sh: line 5: [: 1+1: integer expression expected
```

I have tried using double quotes "" but the results are same.
What changes should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
cp $docid/$p.pdf ./
```

should read:

```
cp "$docid/$p.pdf" ./
```

Example:

```
$ a='abc def'
$ ls $a
ls: abc: No such file or directory
ls: def: No such file or directory
$ ls "$a"
ls: abc def: No such file or directory
```

And arithmetic goes like:

```
p=$[p+1]
```

Example:

```
$ p=1
$ q=$[p+1]
$ echo $p $q
1 2
```

Comment: thanks for making this clear.What exactly is the reason that it is working the way you explained?

Comment: p=$[p+1] is a bashism.  You can do arithmetic more portably with $(( p += 1 )) and even more portably using eval.  ("more portably" means posix, "even more portably" means should work in shells from the 70s)

Comment: @RegisteredUser: `$a` is expanded to `abc def`, so `ls $a` expands to `ls abc def`, i.e. 2 arguments. `ls "$a"` expands to `ls "abc def"`, i.e. 1 argument.

Comment: The `p=$[p+1]` form is deprecated. Use `(( p++ ))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the name containing spaces with double quotes.  Moreover,  `p=$p+1` does not do what you expect.  Here is the corrected loop:

```
for p in `seq 116`; do
    cp "$docid/$p.pdf" ./
done
```

Comment: `{1..116}` could replace the `seq` command or perhaps `seq -f"%03g" 116` (bearing in mind you'll probably want to sort them sooner or later).

Comment: @potong: I know this question is tagged `bash`, but I usually prefer to remember the POSIX-compatible variants instead of the bash-specific extensions.  `seq -f"%03g" 116` is more easily written `seq -w 116`, but both of those won't help much -- the OP obviously wants to copy files named `1.pdf` to `116.pdf`.

Comment: @pontong this is even better thanks for the sorting tip.Yes I do want that.

Comment: @sven seq is hardly portable (it doesn't even exist on OSX)

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I happen to have worked in an area where I was more likely to encounter an AIX machine than an OS X machine, and `seq` used to work quite reliably for me.  I always thought `seq` was a POSIX tool, but maybe I'm wrong.  You can use `jot` instead of `seq` on OS X, but that isn't portable as well.  Do you know a better solution?

Comment: @sven Unfortunately, I do not know a good portable way to emulate seq.  perl -e '$,="\n"; print (1..10)' is my typical replacement.  I've not heard of jot before; thanks for the reference.

Comment: In Bash, use C-style for loops: `for ((p=1; p<=116; p++))`